# is it necessary in Anaconda for Matplotlib to install ffmpeg for animation saving?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg, anaconda

For animation saving I have read some propositions
1) manual installing ffmpeg this way:

```
  conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg
```

2) manual installing ImageMagick and changing matplotlib configuration file "matplotlibrc" this way:

```
#animation.ffmpeg_args: ''         # Additional arguments to pass to ffmpeg
#animation.avconv_path: 'avconv'   # Path to avconv binary. Without full path
                                   # $PATH is searched
#animation.avconv_args: ''         # Additional arguments to pass to avconv
#animation.mencoder_path: 'mencoder'
                                   # Path to mencoder binary. Without full path
                                   # $PATH is searched
#animation.mencoder_args: ''       # Additional arguments to pass to mencoder
#animation.convert_path: 'convert' # Path to ImageMagick's convert binary.
animation.convert_path: F:\Games\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\magick.exe
                                   # On Windows use the full path since convert
                                   # is also the name of a system tool.
```

where line with pass to installed ImageMagick was added manually

```
animation.convert_path: F:\Games\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\magick.exe
```

Two questions:
1 - what way is better for Anaconda?
2 - really Anaconda has no better way????

Comment: I don't know what "better" would mean, but essentially both ways should work.

Comment: for example - when do
    `conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg ` 
some Anaconda parameters are replacing. I think it is not good...

Really I did 3-d way. Install **ImageMagick**, add path to **magick.exe**
to windows PATH, and set the environment:   

`MAGICK_HOME=F:\Games\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\modules\coders`
now all are working without 1) or 2)
But - standard  animation saving  to _*.html_ was crashed (((( 
That's why I am searching way without any loses.

Comment: There is no "standard" saving to html. You would probably like to ask about saving to html then, not about ways to use ffmpeg.

Comment: with matplotlib 2.x when I tried save to *.gif  or *.mp4 I had the nessage like: `file extension have to be *.html or *.htm`
   and all works only with *.html .  But when I did the way 3) I cant do saving to *.html 
**somethings is broken** 
Is the way to all work?
sorry for bad English